# sql query - select on two tables which used data from both tables to filter results

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables with the following columns:

```
tbl_a: id, date, data
tbl_b: id, date, a_id, data
```

in tbl_b.a_id saved the id of tbl_a related record  whitout foreign-key definition.

I wont to select all id from tbl_a where it have 0 records in tbl_b with
tbl_b.a_id = tbl_a.id AND tbl_b.date = tbl_a.date.

Comment: select * from tbl_a  Left Join tbl_b on tbl_a.id=tbl_b.a_id where tbl_b.id IS NULL ... this will help u I think

Comment: Sorry, you wont or want?

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistakes, I mean - 'I wants to'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple NOT EXISTS clause you are looking for (records from tbl_a for which *not exists* an entry in tbl_b):

```
select id
from tbl_a a
where not exists
(
  select *
  from tbl_b b
  where b.a_id = a.id
  and b.date = a.date
);
```

UPDATE: Here is the same with a NOT IN clause, which is even easier to read. This only works, however, when both `tbl_b.a_id` and `tbl_b.date` are not nullable.

```
select id
from tbl_a
where (id, date) not in (select a_id, date from tbl_b);
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
Your solution worked and helped me arrange the thoughts approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT 
tbl_a.id
FROM
tbl_a LEFT JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_b.a_id = tbl_a.id AND tbl_a.date = tbl_b.date
WHERE tbl_b.a_id IS NULL
```

**Note:**
You need to gather some knowledge on MySQL joins specially Left join in order to understand the above query. 
You may take a look at this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

**N:B:** If you don't want to adopt `LEFT JOIN` then you may look at the other answers.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9ae7/2/0)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest an anti-join to an obvious beginner to whom even `NOT EXISTS` doesn't come to mind. An anti-join is a trick used on weak DBMS that have performance issues with EXISTS and IN. So why teach the trick when there is no issue and obviously the straight-forward `[NOT] EXISTS` and `[NOT] IN` haven't yet settled or even been taught.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. But a problem may be approached in different ways. If anyone falls in same problem he might find this particular question and might get an idea that how the problem can be dealt with different ways.